# Where would I get this type of hat?

Tags: product-recommendation, hats

Below is a photo of R' Elio Toaff ז”ל with HH Pope John Paul II. In it, we see R' Toaff wearing a hat traditionally used in certain Ashkenazi and Italki communities, which many Jekkisch chazzanim, such as R' Ezra Lasdun of Breuer's maintain.

Where could one (especially a chazzan or rav) purchase a hat of this type?

[image: R' Elio Toaff w/ HH Pope John Paul II]

[Image source](http://philippi-collection.blogspot.com/2010/12/miznafat-misnafat-miznefet-miznephet.html)

Comment: I was this close to [migrating this question to meta](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: Very funny, DoubleAA :-) This type of Chazzan's cap looks a bit familiar to me. I wonder if I can contact someone at *Sha'arei Tefilla* in Washington Heights. They were a Jekkish shul, but I'm uncertain of how active they are, now. I'll see if I can locate them on the web. Maybe there's some info.

Comment: Is the purchase of any article of clothing worn by any group of Jews throughout history, on topic?

Comment: @DanF - That might be a good idea but maybe contact these guys: http://www.kajinc.org/contact-us I read elsewhere on SE that this is the best way to get a hold of a Western Ashkenazi siddur...

Comment: Worth trying to contact the Livorno community. They may be of help

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but the Chazzon Sheini of Shaare Hatikvah got his made by a local seamstress.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Chaim! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your answer would be more complete if you provided information how to contact the seamstress that made this.